# Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "cryptoNewsApi" has not been added to the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I have created two Api components with redux and then I want to call them both in the store and this is the code I've written

```
import { configureStore} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {cryptoApi} from '../services/cryptoApi';
import {cryptoNewsApi} from '../services/cryptoNewsApi'
export default configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
        [cryptoNewsApi.reducerPath]: cryptoNewsApi.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoApi.middleware),

    // middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    //     getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoNewsApi.middleware),

});
```

and it didn't work
so I recognized that I should add the cryptoNewsApi to the middleware too
How can I do this

Comment: Can you show both API definitions? Also, normally you should only have _one_ `createApi` call in an app, not multiples: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi

Comment: ` middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>         getDefaultMiddleware().concat(cryptoApi.middleware, cryptoNewsApi.middleware)`

Mark, do you mean one `createApi` call in an app, or one `createApi` per actual api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { cryptoApi } from "../services/cryptoApi";
import { CryptoNewsApi } from "../services/CryptoNewsApi";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]: cryptoApi.reducer,
        [CryptoNewsApi.reducerPath]: CryptoNewsApi.reducer
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(
        cryptoApi.middleware,
        CryptoNewsApi.middleware
    )
})
```